# health experts foresee/predict the novel coronavirus spreading in the U.S

Tags: word-usage, differences, gerund-vs-infinitive, predicate-frames

> One of the top officials at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention warned Americans on Tuesday that health experts **foresee** the novel coronavirus that has killed thousands **spreading** in the United States.

If we change **foresee** to its synonym **predict**, **spreading** is not possible.

Can someone explain the different usage?

Comment: I don't understand what you want explained here. Because every verb has its own idiosyncratic rules governing its predicate frame, you can never extrapolate the rules that apply to a given verb based on those that apply to a different one. Each verb's usage pattern is peculiar onto itself and so must be learned from scratch. But as I'm sure you know all of this already, could you please better clarify just what it is that you do wish explained?

Comment: "Predict to spread" is not correct. It would be correct to say, "Health experts predict the novel coronavirus that has killed thousands will spread in the United States." Once you understand this, you are left only to learn the difference in framing between the verb "foresee" and the verb "predict". They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: @RMac Then, this Guardian article must be wrong to write: "One of the many surprise snubs from this week’s Oscar nominations was the exclusion of the blaxploitation biopic Dolemite Is My Name. At this stage of the season, most hadn’t **predicted it to figure in the best picture race** but Eddie Murphy, who had been figuring heavily in the circuit, was seen as a strong contender for best actor." https://www.theguardian.com/film/2020/jan/13/cats-the-goldfinch-oscarbait-movies-academy-2020

Comment: @tchrist Granted, "every verb has its own idiosyncratic rules governing its predicate frame", but should it preempt any attempt to explain the "interesting" difference in allowed forms of complements of synonymous verbs such as these? Note that their predicate frames are also very similar in that both take an NP, a that-clause, a wh-clause, etc. The only difference is the additional complement that can follow an NP complement as shown in the OP. I think that's interesting enough to dig a little deeper.

Comment: @listenava A prediction is by definition an uncertain, however educated, guess that something might happen in the future. It should be tensed appropriately, with a conditional verb. The Guardian article is therefore not correct in its usage. A skilled editor would have caught this and recommended the edit, "At this stage of the season, most hadn’t predicted that it would figure in the best picture race [...]."

Comment: @RMac The "would figure" is not a conditional verb. It's a backshifted verb. Also, 'foresee' is a synonym of 'predict' but it can have the form of "foresee the novel coronavirus spreading".

Comment: You *can* say, regarding the problem, that "it **has** (or **had**) **been predicted *to* grow** worse with time" in either present or past perfect passive. But you *cannot* say that **"you predict the problem *to* get worse** with time" with an infinitive in the active the way you could with *expect*; that one needs to use a modal or periphrastic future saying that "you predict that the problem **will** (or **is going to**) get worse with time". I have no coherent explanation as to why, just some hunches I intend to sleep on.

Comment: @tchrist Okay. I've edited the question.